# (Python) Can I store the functions themselves, but not their value, in a list

Tags: python, list

As you can see from the code below, I'm adding a series of functions to a list.
The result is that each function gets ran and the returned value is added to the list.

```
foo_list = []
foo_list.append(bar.func1(100))
foo_list.append(bar.func2([7,7,7,9]))
foo_list.append(bar.func3(r'C:\Users\user\desktop\output'))
```

What I would like to know is, is it possible to have the function stored in the list and then ran when it is iterated upon in a for loop?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah just use lambda:

```
foo_list = []
foo_list.append(lambda: bar.func1(100))
foo_list.append(lambda: bar.func2([7,7,7,9]))
foo_list.append(lambda: bar.func3(r'C:\Users\user\desktop\output'))

for foo in foo_list:
    print(foo())
```